# Indefinite loop occurs when out of integer range in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

My question is that why an indefinite loop occurs when we try to print numbers from 0 to 32767,

why does it goes back to -32767 and restarts printing.

PROGRAM CODE-

```
main(){

         int i;

         for(i=0; i<=32767; i++){

         printf("%d\n", i);

    }
}
```

Comment: overflow! (but not stack overflow). Try learn the basics on types

Comment: ^ (@jean)-> I will give just a little h**int** !

Comment: not understand what are you saying @jean

Comment: Also just try to change the **<=** to **<** you ill se the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that maximim value of an object of type int (`INT_MAX`) in your environment is equal to 32767. Thus then i is equal to 32767

```
for(i=0; i<=32767; i++){
```

after evaluation expression `i++` the sign bit of the internal representation of i is set and i becomes equal to negative value -32768 that is to `INT_MIN`
In this case condition

```
i<=32767
```

will yield true.

Comment: Thanks now i really understood this

Answer (score 0):

Because 32767 is the maximum value for a 16-bit int.

What else would you expect its value to be after incrementing that by one?